# Talend updation a foreign key row

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio to do the data migration from PostgreSQL to MySQL.
I want to update a row which is a foreign key but I got this error :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`access_stamp`.`t_finger_print`, CONSTRAINT `FK_FP_EMPLOYEE` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`FP_EMPLOYEE_ID`) REFERENCES `t_employee` (`EMP_ID`))

Comment: And the question is? The error message is pretty obvious.

Comment: How to force updating or inserting values in this row ?

Comment: If you want to ignore foreign keys, then why have it. Your data is wrong or you try to update a table before another one was updated to have the sufficient references

Comment: The whole idea is  that I am migrating from PostgreSQL to MySQL so I have 2 tables (which one of them is a FK of the other)

Comment: PostgreSQL database is already existant and contain data and MySQL database is generated by Hibernate with all it's constraints, I hope this clear it a bit !

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert or update a row in your `t_employees` table first that relates to the child table you are trying to insert or update where the `EMP_ID` matches across both tables.

That's all I can suggest given the input you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I added another table as `lookup` and linked with the `id` and now it works fine